# Clang version 1.6 cannot be updated

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, homebrew, rbenv

I have a very strange issue with clang. I'm running OSX 10.10.1 and have installed XCode 6.1.1 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). For another project, I wanted to update Ruby from 2.1.2 to 2.2.0 via `rbenv install 2.2.0`. The command prints the following error:

```
Downloading ruby-2.2.0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7671e394abfb5d262fbcd3b27a71bf78737c7e9347fa21c39e58b0bb9c4840fc
Installing ruby-2.2.0...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.10.1 using ruby-build 20141225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4z/s4lwbd314_lg3hprgp72qsqr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150112115924.6502
Results logged to /var/folders/4z/s4lwbd314_lg3hprgp72qsqr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150112115924.6502.log

Last 10 log lines:
Via: 1.1 2ce6276171358bf7d052aa190ed98f8d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 42q6Sa73ORpGbCgaHIpsBwTRP8ycUAhsdTolikEbyxqMrn9uePtfCA==

/var/folders/4z/s4lwbd314_lg3hprgp72qsqr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150112115924.6502/ruby-2.2.0 /var/folders/4z/s4lwbd314_lg3hprgp72qsqr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150112115924.6502 /usr/bin
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0'
configure: error: clang version 3.0 or later is required
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Googled for `invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0'` but I did not find any helpful information. By running `clang --version` it turns out that my clang executable is version 1.6 (!):

```
Apple clang version 1.6 (tags/Apple/clang-70)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14
Thread model: posix
```

This seems very weird, because [XCode is usually shipped with LLVM 6](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292). I tried to (re)install the Command Line Tools (in which clang should be located), but XCode doesn't offer me the option to download/update them: [image: No Option to Download CLT]

Trying to install them via xcode-select via the command line: `xcode-select --install` as suggested [here](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) results in showing the help message, indicating that the --install-command is unknown (xcode-select is version 895). I also tried to [download and install it manually](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) but it has absolutely no effect. The xcode-select-path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` but I also tried `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

I also tried to [update clang via Homebrew](http://catch-0x16.blogspot.de/2013/07/up-to-date-clang-with-homebrew-on-mac.html):

```
$ brew install llvm --with-clang --with-asan 
[...]
LLVM executables are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin.
Extra tools are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/share/llvm.
$ brew install llvm --with-clang --with-asan
Warning: llvm-3.5.0_2 already installed
```

but in none of the two paths is a clang executable.

So my question is: Is there a way to update clang? Or a workaround to install ruby 2.2.0 anyway? I'm stuck here for days, any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I found out that newer XCode versions (I think from 5.0 upwards) come with LLVM/Clang inside the XCode.app-folder. A few months ago, I installed XCode 4.something for testing purposes - these versions overwrite system tools like clang and xcode-select. Reinstalling XCode 6 will not update them.

I fixed it by copying /usr/bin from another Mac, but there must be a way to fix it without this workaround.

Comment: you mean that your brewed clang is not inside "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin"?

Comment: No, inside "/usr/local/opt" is no symlink to llvm...

Comment: guess that you didn't build llvm successfully; btw, I don't have a "--with-asan" option for brew install of llvm. And have checked **all** clang executables on your mac(including `/usr/bin/clang`)?

Comment: What do you mean, I didn't build it successfully? I never built LLVM from source, I excpect it to come with OSX and/or XCode. The executable under `/usr/bin/clang` is the only one, according to the output of `where clang`. Of course was the executable under XCode.app not shown...

Comment: `brew install` builds llvm(with clang) from source. Use `which -a clang` to see *all* clang in `$PATH`.